# When random walk Markov matrix of the graph is normal?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, markov-chains

I'm considering random walk on undirected graph $G$. At every time step, walker moves to a random neighbour, with all neighbours being equally likely.

With adjacency matrix $A$ the random walk Markov matrix will be $M = D^{-1}A$, where $D$ is diagonal matrix with $D_{i,i}$ being sum of $i$-th row of matrix $A$. Under which conditions on $G$ matrix $M$ will be normal?

Comment: And... your thoughts on the question are?

Comment: @Did It seems for normality of $M$ I need $D^{-1}$ and $A$ to commute for which I need $A_{i,j} = 0$ whenever $D^{-1}_{i,i} \neq D^{-1}_{j,j}$ and now I doubt such graphs even exist.

Comment: For connected graphs, this means every vertex has the same degree (of course such graphs exist, they are called *regular*).

Comment: @Did, exactly. Thank you.